# Proving another space is contractible using the homotopy extension property

Tags: algebraic-topology

Question 4 in the first exercise section in Spanier's, *Algebraic Topology* is stated as follows:

"Prove that a space $Y$  is contractible if and only if, given a pair ($X$,$A$) having the homotopy extension property with respect to $Y$, any map $A\rightarrow Y$ can be extended over $X$."

I figured out how to go from the first statement to the second but not the other way. Any hints on how to start the other implication?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try taking $(X,A)=(Y\times [0,1], Y\times \{0,1\})$.